# Why does yfinance data gives different numbers through times of day

Tags: python, for-loop, yfinance

I'm a beginner in Python and I've been doing a project on a stock screener for one of my classes. I create a csv list of several tickers, run through those lists to get data from yfinance and then use that to go through a set of criteria. Here's the loop I use to get data from yfinance:

```
for i in allrecs:
    stock = yf.Ticker(i[0])
    PriceEarning = stock.info["forwardPE"]
    cap = stock.info["marketCap"]
    dividend = stock.info["dividendYield"]
    dividend_output = formatpercentage(dividend)
    cap_formatted = "${:,.0f}".format(cap)
    beta = stock.info['beta']
    # result = condition(EPS_forward)
    # rec = i[0], result
    print(i[0],PriceEarning, cap, dividend, beta)
```

The problem I'm having is, on different times of days I receive different numbers. For example, when I was working on the file at 2pm they returned dividend yield and beta, but now at 4pm they all return "None". Also, when I retrieve the data from individual ticker, I got the number but when I was running it through the loop, it returned "None". How should I fix it?

Comment: don't you get error message? create minimal working data. Maybe you run it in wrong way. As I know some stocks are closed at some days/hours so you may not get data.

Comment: There were no error messages, they simply returned "none". Stocks closing at certain days/hours might be the case. Is there a way to make the number not changing?

Comment: get values when they are avaliable and keep in local file/database - and next time when you get `None` from `yf` then load values from file/database. And if you get new values them save them again in file/database.